# Crear apk con Visual Studio Code

Tags: ionic-framework, apk, vscode

Alguien sabe alguna manera de generar el archivo .apk, ¿desde Visual Studio Code? ¿O si se puede? ¿Debería firmar la aplicación no?

El código esta basado en `ionic framework` con `Angular 4.4`.

He visto muchos tutoriales pero todos usan el compilador `Microsoft Visual Studio`. Yo estoy usando `visual studio code`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buscando un poco más profundo en la web, he encontrado que si se puede.

Primero debes asegurarte de que tienes todo el SetUp instalado:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/installation/android

Y posteriormente, puedes crear el apk y firmarlo:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/publishing/play-store

Answer (score 1):

Con visual `Studio Code` no se si se pueda ,pero para firmar la apk puedes usar el metodo tradicional que es instalar  `Android Studio`

Recuerda hacer copia de seguridad del archivo **`key store.jks`** cuando la firmes si tenes alguna duda con este procedimiento comenta por aqui.

Comment: Por lo tanto, tengo que abrir el repositoro con Android Studio y buscar algun tutorial sobre ello?

Comment: Muy fácil mira en  `visual studio code` lo que debes hacer es `ionic build android --release`  eso genera los archivos  en la carpteta `Miapp\platforms\android`

Comment: Luego abres `androidStudio` click en `Open an existing Android Studio project` y buscas la carpeta `Miapp\platforms\android`

Comment: luego en el menu  `build` y `Generate singned APK`